# How to use java efflux library

Tags: java, rtsp, rtp

Recently I found a RTP/RTSP library on https://github.com/jonbo372/efflux.  I want to learn and use the project,but I could not get any the examples or manual.  Can anybody provide these materials?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make it work but I *think* it must be something like this:

```
String server = "example.com";  // you need to set this
long ssrc = 0; // you need to set this
String sessionid = "???"; // you need to set this
int server_data_port = 0; // you need to set this
int server_ctrl_port = 0; // you need to set this
int my_data_port = 8000; // you can pick this
int my_ctrl_port = 8001; // you can pick this
int payloadType = 0;    // set from RTP spec.  I want to send H.264 but don't see a number for that.  http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtp-parameters/rtp-parameters.xml

RtpParticipant pThem = RtpParticipant.createReceiver(server, server_data_port, server_ctrl_port);
pThem.getInfo().setSsrc(ssrc);

RtpParticipant pMe = RtpParticipant.createReceiver("0.0.0.0", my_data_port, my_ctrl_port);
pMe.getInfo().setSsrc(ssrc); // I guess both have the same ssrc?

RtpSession session = new SingleParticipantSession(sessionid, payloadType, pMe, pThem);

session.addDataListener(new RtpSessionDataListener() {
    @Override
    public void dataPacketReceived(RtpSession session, RtpParticipantInfo participant, DataPacket packet) {
             // Do something with the data
        }});

session.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

None seem easily available.  You could try looking over the tests [here](https://github.com/jonbo372/efflux/tree/master/src/test/java/com/biasedbit/efflux), to get an idea of usage.

Comment: I looked all the test codes,but each one just refer to  a small part of the project. It haven't a complete example of RTP session.